# iphone app loading data in language other than english

Tags: ios, fonts

Hai i am very new to iPhone app development and just want to develop a newspaper app in a local language and my problem is how can i load the data in a particular language other than english

Answer (score 0):

Localisation is an integral part of an app. Click [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial) for a simple tutorial on it.

Hope you find it useful.